# GAN training - Preserving gradients when passing generator output through a non-differentiable function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement a simple GAN model by following the official Tensorflow [DCGAN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan). Posting the entire code here would be overkill, but for all practical purposes my code can be considered the same as the reference implementation. I did make changes to the layer architecture in both the discriminator and generator, but all of those modifications are ultimately irrelevant to my problem, with one key exception - the generator output layer.

Instead of outputting an image directly, like most generators do, I need mine to output some 1D feature vector instead. This feature vector is essentially a list of independent variables, which get converted to images by some `featuresToImages()` function in a deterministic and non-reversible fashion, and the resulting images can in turn be fed to the discriminator. To be clear, by "deterministic and non-reversible" I mean that the same feature vector will always generate an identical image, but there's no way of mapping a preexisting image back to this feature space. So, the output of my generator is the same shape/size as my feature vector. Which brings us to the crux of my problem, at least if the last couple of days of googling and getting nowhere have taught me anything...

I tested the discriminator, generator and `featuresToImages()` function independently, and they all work as expected. The problem crops up when I get to the training loop, or rather training step. The relevant code is:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(images):
    noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, noise_dim])
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
        generated_features = generator(noise, training=True)
        generated_images = featuresToImages(generated_features) # Problem line - necessary but non-differentiable set of operations

        real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
        fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

        gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
        disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
```

My generator output isn't images, so I can't pass it directly to the discriminator like in the reference example.
If I convert the generator output to images via my `featuresToImages()` function, that's a non-differentiable operation, so I lose the generator gradients - `gradients_of_generator` returns a list of `None` values, so `generator_optimizer.apply_gradients` throws an exception, and the generator can't be trained.
I can't change the generator output, as that would defeat the entire point of the project.
I can't change the discriminator input, since I also need to pass it real images (my training dataset), which can't be reverse-mapped to a feature vector.

Is there anything I can do to make this concept work, or is it just a lost cause? Maybe a third "mapping" network that would learn how a specific feature vector correlates to a specific image output, ie. it would learn to represent the `featuresToImages()` function, be differentiable, and preserve the gradients between generator and discriminator? Though there's hopefully an obvious (to non-noobs like me) and cleaner solution/workaround that doesn't require an entire new subnet to implicitly learn an already explicitly defined function...

Comment: Hi @Kaoru, is it possible to share your code for featuresToImage()? I have several options in my mind but want to be certain which one applies to your problem before writing an answer.

Comment: If you’re thinking of simply refactoring the function to be differential, I’m afraid that isn’t an option. You can imagine a part of it going through a third party application/format which is either a) a black box that can’t be reverse-engineered or b) can be reverse-engineered, but doing so would be prohibitively complex, to the point where simply adding the third mapping network would be orders of magnitude simpler to implement.